# Iterate through all objects or create map. What is better solution

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I have enum:

```
public enum Colour {
   RED, BLUE, BLACK;
}
```

And I have Car class:

```
public class Car {
   private int id;
   private Colour colour;
   //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

And I have a lot of cars in `Map<Integer, Car> MAP_OF_CARS`. And I have to display for example all cars which are red. So here is my question, what is better solution. Iterate through all cars in map or to create map, where list of cars will be defined by colour?

First solution:

```
public List<Car> getCarsByColor(Colour colour) {
   List<Car> sameColour = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Car car : MAP_OF_CARS.values()) {
      if(car.getColour().equals(colour) {
         sameColour.add(car);
      }
   }
   return sameColour;
}
```

Second solution: During creating new car object, I will add it to the Map and in result I will have:

```
Map<Colour, List<Car>> CARS_BY_COLOURS;
CARS_BY_COLOURS.put(Colour.RED, car1);
```

And instead of for loop, I will be doing this:

```
public List<Car> getCarsByColor(Colour colour) {
   return CARS_BY_COLOURS.get(colour);
}
```

Which solution seems to be more professional?

Comment: Usually the map is the more straightforward solution, but it depends on the amount of keys and your performance and memory constraints. There's no single correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "right" or "wrong" here, it's a matter of what's more appropriate for your application.

The first solution always goes through all the cars. Assuming you have a more-or-less uniform distributions of cars by color, this would mean iterating over three times as many cars.

The second solution, on the other hand, gives you easy access to the cars of the requested color, but has some memory overhead of holding a second map.

It all boils down to the application's requirements. If getting all the cars by color is a rare operation, or if memory requirements are a concern, the first solution could be preferred.
If getting all the cars of a certain color is a common operation in the application, the second option would probably be better.

Answer (score 3):

> what is better solution. Iterate through all cars in map or to create map, where list of cars will be defined by colour?

It depends on how frequently you are searching and how frequently you are updating.

Generally speaking if you only have two things you are looking for (id and color in this example) parallel maps is the most straightforward solution.

If you are looking at more than a couple you will need to better consider frequency, constantly updating a map you rarely use is not ideal.

Depending on how many objects and properties you have you may also want to consider using an external data storage method such as a SQL server (MySQL, MSSQL or whatever) which will do a lot of these types of optimizations for you.